# ssh to openstack instance from other then controller node

Tags: devops, openstack, iptables, nat

I have an openstack(microstack) instance running on my server (ubuntu 20.04): S1. I have an ubuntu (20.04) instance up and running on it (floating ip 10.20.20.100), on which ping 8.8.8.8 works. I can ssh and ping this instance with FIP from the controller node/S1.

**My intention is to access this server from my local machine (!=S1) (via WSL) with the floating IP.**
LOCAL_PC(WSL)$> ssh 10.20.20.100

I'm looking into using NAT (S/D) but I could use some clarification on what is the proper way of performing such forwarding!

Thank you in advance!
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSH [ProxyJump](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J) to do this. Using your Ubuntu server as a proxy or 'jump host'.

```
  ssh -J user@proxy user@vm
```

Comment: thank you, good to know that there are more than one ways of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the solution for the questioned problem:

I've issued the following command on my local machine to ssh the vm:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o ProxyCommand='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -W %h:%p <user>@<jumphost/controller_node>' <user>@<target_instance_in_openstack=10.20.20.100>
```